# GAv4 Discarding hit. Missing hit type parameter: tid=_GTM_DEFAULT_TRACKER_

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are implementing Google Analytics on Android & iOS using the Google Tag Manager's legacy containers, the screenview tracking is working fine however the custom event hits are discarded with the above error.

Screenview firing code:

```
dataLayer.PushEvent("screen1", DataLayer.MapOf("screenName", "Sample Screen"));
```

Custom Event firing code:

`dataLayer.PushEvent("event1", DataLayer.MapOf("eventCategory", "Sample Category", "eventAction", "Sample Action", "eventLabel", "Sample Label"));`

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: nope, currently passing the custom event parameters as a screen name in a separate screen view tag.